# ImportError: cannot import name 'coco' while trainng images by tensorflow using EdjeElectronics tutorial

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, github

Here I'm training own images by tensorflow using [EdjeElectronics from Github](https://github.com/EdjeElectronics/TensorFlow-Object-Detection-API-Tutorial-Train-Multiple-Objects-Windows-10). While  run the following command in cmd,

> `python model_main.py --logtostderr --train_dir=training/ --pipeline_config_path=training/faster_rcnn_inception_v2_pets.config`

I got following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "model_main.py", line 26, in 
from object_detection import model_lib
File "C:\Users\Sa\PycharmProjects\Training _Tensorflow\models\research
\object_detection\model_lib.py", line 27, in 
from object_detection import eval_util
File "C:\Users\Sa\PycharmProjects\Training _Tensorflow\models\research
\object_detection\eval_util.py", line 27, in 
from object_detection.metrics import coco_evaluation
File "C:\Users\Sa\PycharmProjects\Training _Tensorflow\models\research
\object_detection\metrics\coco_evaluation.py", line 20, in 
from object_detection.metrics import coco_tools
File "C:\Users\Sa\PycharmProjects\Training _Tensorflow\models\research
\object_detection\metrics\coco_tools.py", line 47, in 
from pycocotools import coco
ImportError: cannot import name 'coco'
```

Then refered some [from pycocotools.coco import COCO fails](https://github.com/cocodataset/cocoapi/issues/14) discussion, then i downloaded the CocoAPI for python from https://github.com/philferriere/cocoapi#subdirectory=PythonAPI and i pasted the folder in the **Tensorflow\models\research** Path.(However the EdjeElectronics Tutorial didn't mentioned about cocoAPI installation).

Still the getting the **from pycocotools import coco
ImportError: cannot import name 'coco'** error. (one week i'm searching on this.)

Comment: make sure whatever path you care copying the api to is in sys.path. Else the python interpreter would not be able to load the package/ module
Try,
import sys
sys.path    #see what all directories are printed

Comment: i already tried by copying  the COCAPI into the python path, then i found that i need to copy the directory into the tensorflow\models\research path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the issue is with the model_main.py file, when we use it then it will shows the cannot import name 'coco' error.
Copy the train.py file from object_detection\legacy folder and paste it on the object_detection folder. Then run the following command in the command prompt . Make sure that u are on the 'object_detection' directory and ensure that u run the pre-training commands mentioned in the [tutorial](https://github.com/EdjeElectronics/TensorFlow-Object-Detection-API-Tutorial-Train-Multiple-Objects-Windows-10)

> ```
> python train.py --logtostderr --train_dir=training/
> --pipeline_config_path=training/faster_rcnn_inception_v2_pets.config
> ```